# Why does it seem completely random if ls -lrt returns last modifed year or not?

Tags: unix, ls

Here are the results of a ls -lrt command in unix:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 blah      blah          846       Apr 18  2013 filetype1.log
-rw-r--r--   1 blah      blah          290338533 Jan  3 00:59 filetype2.log
```

Why does one conveniently return the year while the other just has month, day, and time stamp? How can I always get the year?

EDIT:
Here's an example where the last edit time was NOT within the current year and still no year:

```
-rw-r--r--   1 blah      blah       689466 Dec 31 23:59 filetype2.log
-rw-r--r--   1 blah      blah       689591 Jan  1 00:59 filetype2.log
```

Comment: Because that file without a year was modified in the current year...

Comment: @DarkFalcon See edit for another example addressing your case

Comment: If you're using the GNU Coreutils version of `ls`, the `--full-time` option gives you a consistent representation of the timestamp (possibly with nanoseconds). If you're thinking of writing a program to parse the output of `ls`, you should probably take a different approach; `ls` output is designed to be human-readable, not necessarily machine-parsable.  If you're not writing a program, then your question is off-topic, and would probably be better suited for the [Unix site](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @KeithThompson I am writing a program that needs last modified (or creation) date.  Better options to get this than ls?

Comment: Unix does not store a "creation" date for files. The best way to get the last modification date depends on what language you're using, but either `stat` or something that calls `stat` is probably your best choice.

Comment: @KeithThompson Its a C# program, I'm SSHing into a unix server and runing unix command line.

Comment: So you can't install and run some program on the target system? If the target system has the coreutils `stat` command, try `stat -c %z filename` or `stat -c %Z filename`; the latter is likely to be easier to parse.

Comment: @KeithThompson Judging by the fact that running `stat -c %z filename` produced the result `cd: Too many arguments`, I'm guessing I don't have access to it.  Its a production server so I'm not allowed to install anything on it without a massive ROI presentation/approval loop.  Any other options?

Comment: `cd: Too many arguments` doesn't make any sense. Is `stat` a shell function or alias? What do `type -a stat` and `stat --version` tell you? Are there any funny characters in the filename (that need to be quoted)?

Comment: @KeithThompson `type -a stat` gave me `/usr/bin/type[6]: whence: A specified flag is not valid for this command.`, and `stat --version` gave me `cd: Too many arguments`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44810/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-hershizer33)

Comment: @KeithThompson Unfortunately my work firewall blocks any kind of IM :/

Comment: Really? If you can access a web site, you should be able to use chat; your firewall shouldn't know the difference between posting comments here and posting chat messages. You tried the "continue this discussion in chat" link? If you really can't use chat: Exactly what OS is the target system running, and what do `type stat` and `which stat` tell you?

Comment: And if you really can't use `stat`, and you do have GNU Coreutils `ls`, see [Formatting file timestamps](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Formatting-file-timestamps.html); in addition to what [the accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21003702/827263) quotes, you can specify the format yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the GNU Coreutils manual:

### 10.1.6 Formatting file timestamps

By default, file timestamps are listed in abbreviated form, using a date
like 'Mar 30  2002' for non-recent timestamps, and a date-without-year
and time like 'Mar 30 23:45' for recent timestamps.  This format can
change depending on the current locale as detailed below.

A timestamp is considered to be "recent" if it is less than six
months old, and is not dated in the future.  If a timestamp dated today
is not listed in recent form, the timestamp is in the future, which
means you probably have clock skew problems which may break programs
like 'make' that rely on file timestamps.

Comment: Perfect, needed a hard and fast date like 6 months.  Thanks!

Comment: To make my eyes and brain less confused `ls -lrt --time-style="+%Y%m%d:%H%M%S"`

Answer (score 1):

Based on discussion in comments and [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44810/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-hershizer33), you're trying to get the modification time of a file on a remote system in a C# program, and you're not able to install any software on the remote system (which is running HP-UX).

(You also mentioned file creation time, but Unix doesn't store that information, just modification time, access time, and time of most recent inode change).

Since the system doesn't have GNU Coreutils installed, you can't use either `ls --time-style=...` or the `stat` command.

But since it does have Perl, you can obtain a file's modification time with a very simple Perl script, using the built-in `stat` function.

The simplest way to display a timestamp from Perl is as the number of seconds since the Unix epoch, 1970-01-01 00:00:00 GMT; that's also likely to be the simplest format to parse from a C# program.

Create this script on the remote system:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

foreach my $file (@ARGV) {
    my @stat = stat $file;
    if (defined $stat[9]) {
        print "$stat[9] $file\n";
    }
    else {
        die "$file: $!\n";
    }
}
```

and make it executable (`chmod +x script-file-name`). You can then invoke it with one or more file names as command-line arguments; for each file, it will print its modification time and its name.

Parsing the output from your C# program is left as an exercise.

If you had the GNU Coreutils `stat` command, you could do this instead:

```
stat -c '%Z %n' filename
```

You can do something similar with `ls`:

```
ls --time-style=+%s filename
```

but that prints additional information and is harder to parse. `ls` output is intended to be human-readable, not necessarily machine-parsable -- which is probably part of the reason the `stat` command exists.